# beamer handout without alerts

Tags: beamer, overlays, handout

I have a slide, that uses `\pause` and `\alert`, to successively uncover what I am talking about. Since the non-handout version is a bit long I'll just [link](http://fbence.web.elte.hu/mwepresentation.pdf) it. Works superb. But going into handout mode produces the following:

[image]

As you can see, the `\alert`-s are shown in red, which is very confusing on the handout, as it was used to animate the thing. What is also confusing is that the `itemize` environment works as I would have expected, without showing using `\alert` on the text in handout. How can I have the handout version NOT show any red alerts? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample side}
\framesubtitle{with a subtitle}

Start
\begin{itemize}[<+(1)-| alert@+(1)>]
\item  first item 
\vspace{1cm}
\item second item 
\vspace{1cm}
\item  third item
\end{itemize}
\pause
\alert<.(1)>{alert}
\pause

\alert<.(1)>{alert2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the handout to show the text of "alert" and "alert2"?

Comment: Yes, in black, like the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to remove the red highlighting from the handout, you can use `\alert<.(1)|handout:0>{alert}` or `\action<alert@.(1)>{alert}`
- In case you want to remove content completely from the handout, you can use `\only<beamer>{}`

---

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample side}
\framesubtitle{with a subtitle}

Start
\begin{itemize}[<+(1)-| alert@+(1)>]
\item  first item 
\vspace{1cm}
\item second item 
\vspace{1cm}
\item  third item
\end{itemize}
\pause
\alert<.(1)|handout:0>{alert}
\pause
\action<alert@.(1)>{alert}
\pause

\only<beamer>{
    \alert<.(1)>{alert2}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do I have to be explicit about handout here, but not in the `itemize`?

Comment: @fbence I don't know, perhaps 'itemize' is just smarter than `alert` alone?

Comment: perhaps I should ask that as a separate question then :)

Comment: @fbence Would be interesting.

Comment: did so: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311027/beamer-handout-alert-difference-between-itemize-and-simple-alert